# htaccess - allow certain parameters but redirect to 404 if other query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Following problem:
I have a form on a page and want to allow certain parameters to enable form value overwriting. But if there is a questionmark in the url without any of the parameter I want to redirect to the 404 page.

But my regex doesn't work very well...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(a=.*|b=.*|c=.*)
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

But now my page only shows up if a parameter is set. http://example.com/subfolder/ does not work, but http://example.com/subfolder/?a=whatever works. I only want a redirect if there is a question mark without any my parameters. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)(a|b|c)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^subfolder/(.*)$ - [R=404,L,NC]
```

First condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .` makes sure that QUERY_STRING is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm ;)